# parallel execution with extjs grid

Tags: extjs, parallel-processing, extjs3

I am using the extjs data store. In my application when I perform the insertion more than few 100 records, there is a considerable delay in populating the grid. What can be done to improve the performance. I am relatively new to extjs. Is there a way to split all the volume of records into several threads using web workers. Does extjs allow for inserting records after a certain gap as each portion gets filled parallel.

Answer (score 0):

ExtJs draws every single data update to the browser. This painting operations and recalculations lead to huge performance losses.
For such cases there is the possibility to interrupt the drawings in ExtJs:

```
Ext.suspendLayouts();
// insert your hundreds of records here
Ext.resumeLayouts(true);
```